# Is there a closed form PDF for this distribution?

Tags: normal-distribution, sampling

Consider the situation where I sample $x$ from $N(\mu, \sigma)$, and then I sample $y$ from $N(x, \sigma')$ where $\mu$, $\sigma$, and $\sigma'$ are fixed parameters.

1. Is there a closed form PDF for the random variable $y$?
2. Does this kind of situation (i.e. allowing a distribution parameter to be a random variable) have a name? I tried searching "nested distributions" to no avail.

Comment: In effect you have $Y$'s distribution being defined as conditional on $X$.  $Y$ does have a closed form probability density function, as does $X$.

Comment: ans to 2) it's called a "hierarchical model"

Answer (score 1):

Often it is written in that hierarchical form because it is used for simulation. Then that form is more useful than the closed form you ask for.

But the closed form is easy to find. You can write $y = x + \epsilon$ where  $\epsilon \sim \mathcal{N}(0, \sigma')$. Then using that $x \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu, \sigma)$, you can see that $y$ is the sum of two independent normal distributed random variables, and it follows that
$$ y \sim\mathcal{N}\left(\mu, \sqrt{\sigma^2 + \sigma'²}\right) .$$